# PS script generating single alert for multiple windows event ID

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have created PS script to notify me via email when any account in Active Directory is deleted. I attached script with the relevant EVENT.

Using ADUC (GUI) on the AD server, If I delete single user account, I receive notification BUT if I try to DELETE TWO users at a time by selecting BOTH User accounts, the script sends two alerts for same user , not for each
example if i Delete two users TEST1, TEST2 then i receive 2 notifications but only for last 1st deleted users

In event viewer I can see each user Event separately. but What I have noticed that maybe dueto same datetime of events, the get-event is getting last event only. If I delete single user one by one, then alerts works fine for each user.

PS Script:

```
# Script to get event details & sends email or echo output
Cls
###### Modification Starts here
$EventID = “4726”
$From = “MYCOMP.ADMonitor@mymailsrv.com”
$To1 = “admin1@mymailsrv.com”
$SmtpServer = “10.0.01”
###### Modification Ends here
$GetEvent = Get-EventLog -LogName “Security” -InstanceID $EventID -Newest 1
$EventTime = $GetEvent.TimeGenerated
$GetEventMessage = $GetEvent.Message
$AccountSid = $($GetEvent.ReplacementStrings[3])
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier (“$AccountSid”)
$Account = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$messageParametersTo1 = @{
Subject = “$EventID – $env:computername – $Account – Account DELETED”
Body = “EventID: $EventID – $env:computername – $objUser – Account DELETED on $EventTime. nnEvent Details: nn $GetEventMessage nn nn`Script Powered by XZY / MYCOMP IS Dept”
From = “$From”
To = “$To1”
SmtpServer = “$SmtpServer”
}
Send-MailMessage @messageParametersTo1
```

Comment: This line `$GetEvent = Get-EventLog -LogName “Security” -InstanceID $EventID -Newest 1` will only retrieve the most latest event. Specifically the `-Newest 1` parameter. I assume you have this running as a scheduled task? If so how often are you running the task?

Comment: Also do you want an individual email for each event or for them all to be in 1 email?

Comment: I want to receive individual email for each deleted users separately. I have attached the script with the event ID 4726. so as soon the event fires, script runs and send notification. it works fine if I delete single user, but if I select two user and delete them in single Go , in event both users deletion datetime stamp is same, so maybe its the problem. it sends two email but for same user. I tried removing the newest parameter but no use.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to approach this is to pass event information through to the task:

1, Export your current scheduled task as an xml file and make the following modifications:

Insert the following after the "Subscription" element in "/Task/Triggers/EventTrigger"

```
 <ValueQueries>
   <Value name="IndexID">Event/System/EventRecordID</Value>
 </ValueQueries>
```

Adjust the lines in the elements "Task/Actions/Exec/command" & "Task/Actions/Exec/Arguments" to the following replacing the filepath with the path of your script:

```
<Command>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</Command>
<Arguments>-Command <Path of Script File> '$(IndexID)'</Arguments>
```

Import the modified task back into task scheduler so that the variable will now be available to the script

2, Adjust your powershell script to accept the new variable that will be passed through:

```
# Script to get event details & sends email or echo output
Cls
###### Modification Starts here
$EventID = “4726”
$From = “MYCOMP.ADMonitor@mymailsrv.com”
$To1 = “admin1@mymailsrv.com”
$SmtpServer = “10.0.01”
###### Modification Ends here
$GetEvent = Get-EventLog -LogName “Security” -Index $Args[0] # Modified to use index instead of -InstanceID & -newest, the newly passed through variable is inserted into an array of $Args.
$EventTime = $GetEvent.TimeGenerated
$GetEventMessage = $GetEvent.Message
$AccountSid = $($GetEvent.ReplacementStrings[3])
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier (“$AccountSid”)
$Account = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$messageParametersTo1 = @{
    Subject = “$EventID – $env:computername – $Account – Account DELETED”
    Body = “EventID: $EventID – $env:computername – $objUser – Account DELETED on $EventTime. nnEvent Details: nn $GetEventMessage nn nn`Script Powered by XZY / MYCOMP IS Dept”
    From = “$From”
    To = “$To1”
    SmtpServer = “$SmtpServer”
}
Send-MailMessage @messageParametersTo1
```

This will now use the index id (named EventRecordID in the event.) of the event to pull through the correct record from event viewer. I have commented the row `$GetEvent = Get-EventLog -LogName “Security” -Index $Args[0]` to explain the differences.

It is slower to pull the event this way however it will be the correct event for each triggered task.

More about this process of importing data from the triggered event into the executed script is available on this link:

https://michlstechblog.info/blog/windows-passing-parameters-to-event-triggered-schedule-tasks/